# Is there a finished drawing event or callback in the Google Maps API v3?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'd like to pop up a loading bar for when things are loading on a map.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
  // insert / show your loading bar
  // (or not if it's already visible in the DOM)

  // var map = new google.maps.Map(map_canvas, map_options);

  google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'idle', function() {
    // hide your loading bar
  });
```